# Vue watch not noticing changes on component prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I have a basic storage calculator and I pass some of these calculated values to my chart.js component in it props. My issue is that when a value changes inside the prop the watcher doesn't notice it. Why is this happening?

```js
Vue.component('chart', {
    template: '<canvas id="chart"></canvas>',
    props: {
        totals: Array,
    },
    watch: { 
        totals: {
            deep: true,
            handler() {
                console.log('Prop changed');
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createChart() {
            new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Bar Dataset',
                        data: [10, 20, 30, 40]
                    }, {
                        label: 'Line Dataset',
                        data: [50, 50, 50, 50],
                        type: 'line'
                    }],
                    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April']
                }
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.createChart();
    }
});

var app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#savings_calculator',
    data: {
        dataAmount: '42',
        growingRate: '35',
        currencySymbol: 'GBP',
        expertCost: '50000',
        managedData: '150',
        storageBackupCost: '2000',
        obsolescence: '30',
        withDocCostTotals: [,,,,],
        withoutDocCostTotals: [,,,,],
    },
    methods: {
     storageVolCalcWithoutDoc(years) {
            return Math.round(((this.growingRate / 100 + 1)**years)*this.dataAmount);
        },
        smeCostCalcWithoutDoc(years) {
            let value = Math.round((this.dataAmount*((this.growingRate / 100 + 1)**years) / this.managedData)*this.expertCost);
            this.withoutDocCostTotals[years - 1] = value;
            return this.currencyFormat(value);
        },
        hardwareBackupCalcWithoutDoc(years) {
            let value = Math.round((this.dataAmount*( (this.growingRate / 100 + 1)**years ) )*this.storageBackupCost);
            this.withoutDocCostTotals[years - 1] = this.withoutDocCostTotals[years - 1] + value;
            return this.currencyFormat(value);
        },
        storageVolCalcWithDoc(years) {
            return Math.round((Math.abs(this.obsolescence / 100 - 1)*this.dataAmount)*((this.growingRate / 100 + 1)**years));
        },
        smeCostCalcWithDoc(years) {
            let value = Math.round(Math.abs(this.obsolescence / 100 - 1)*(this.dataAmount*((this.growingRate / 100 + 1)**years) / this.managedData)*this.expertCost);
            this.withDocCostTotals[years - 1] = value;
            return this.currencyFormat(value);
        },
        hardwareBackupCalcWithDoc(years) {
         let value = Math.round(Math.abs(this.obsolescence / 100 - 1)*(this.dataAmount*( (this.growingRate / 100 + 1)**years ) )*this.storageBackupCost);
            this.withDocCostTotals[years - 1] = this.withDocCostTotals[years - 1] + value;
            return this.currencyFormat(value);
        },
        annualSavings(year) {
            let value = this.withoutDocCostTotals[year - 1] - this.withDocCostTotals[year - 1];
            return this.currencyFormat(value);
        },
        cumulativeSavings(year) {
            let value = 0;

            for(let i = 0; i < year; i++) {
                value = value + this.withoutDocCostTotals[i] - this.withDocCostTotals[i];
            }

            return this.currencyFormat(value);
        },
        currencyFormat(value) {
         return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { 
                style: 'currency', 
                currency: this.currencySymbol,
                maximumFractionDigits: 0,
       minimumFractionDigits: 0,
            }).format(value);
        }
 }
});
```

```css
label{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="savings_calculator">
  <div class="input container">
    <label>
      <span>How many Terabytes of unstructured data do you have?</span>
      <input type="number" v-model="dataAmount">
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>This is growing a what rate a year?</span>
      <input type="number" v-model="growingRate">%
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>This analysis will be carried out in</span>
      <select id="currency" v-model="currencySymbol">
        <option value="GBP">Gbp</option>
        <option value="USD">Usd</option>
      </select>
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>Annual cost per head for storage experts</span>
      <span v-if="currencySymbol == 'GBP'">£</span>
      <span v-else>$</span>
      <input type="number" v-model="expertCost">
      <!-- prepend currency symbol: number with commas -->
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>One storage expert is required to manage how much data?</span>
      <input type="number" v-model="managedData">
    </label>


    <label>
      <span>Storage and backup costs per TB (p.a)</span>
      <input type="number" v-model="storageBackupCost">
    </label>

    <label>
      <span>Obsolescence target</span>
      <input type="number" v-model="obsolescence">%
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="output container">
    <div class="details">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Storage Volume</th>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithoutDoc(1) }}TB</td>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithoutDoc(2) }}TB</td>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithoutDoc(3) }}TB</td>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithoutDoc(4) }}TB</td>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithoutDoc(5) }}TB</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Without Doc</th>
          <th>Costs for storage SME</th>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithoutDoc(1) }}</td>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithoutDoc(2) }}</td>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithoutDoc(3) }}</td>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithoutDoc(4) }}</td>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithoutDoc(5) }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Hardware and backup costs</th>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithoutDoc(1) }}</td>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithoutDoc(2) }}</td>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithoutDoc(3) }}</td>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithoutDoc(4) }}</td>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithoutDoc(5) }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Storage Volume</th>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithDoc(1) }}TB</td>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithDoc(2) }}TB</td>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithDoc(3) }}TB</td>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithDoc(4) }}TB</td>
          <td>{{ storageVolCalcWithDoc(5) }}TB</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>With Doc</th>
          <th>Costs for storage SME</th>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithDoc(1) }}</td>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithDoc(2) }}</td>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithDoc(3) }}</td>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithDoc(4) }}</td>
          <td>{{ smeCostCalcWithDoc(5) }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Hardware and backup costs</th>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithDoc(1) }}</td>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithDoc(2) }}</td>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithDoc(3) }}</td>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithDoc(4) }}</td>
          <td>{{ hardwareBackupCalcWithDoc(5) }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Year 1</th>
          <th>Year 2</th>
          <th>Year 3</th>
          <th>Year 4</th>
          <th>Year 5</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>obsolescence savings (annual)</th>
          <td>{{ annualSavings(1) }}</td>
          <td>{{ annualSavings(2) }}</td>
          <td>{{ annualSavings(3) }}</td>
          <td>{{ annualSavings(4) }}</td>
          <td>{{ annualSavings(5) }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>obsolescence savings (cumulative)</th>
          <td>{{ cumulativeSavings(1) }}</td>
          <td>{{ cumulativeSavings(2) }}</td>
          <td>{{ cumulativeSavings(3) }}</td>
          <td>{{ cumulativeSavings(4) }}</td>
          <td>{{ cumulativeSavings(5) }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <chart v-if="withDocCostTotals.length" v-bind:totals="withDocCostTotals" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) - Vue cannot detect the changes to an array if you using it like

```
this.withDocCostTotals[years - 1] = value;
```

you should use `Vue.set`:

```
Vue.set(this.withDocCostTotals, years - 1, value);
```

Comment: If I add that code I get the following error ```[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.```

Comment: There is another issue with your code - try to avoid use `{{ anyMethod(1) }}` in your code, use computed properties instead, fixed code here - https://jsfiddle.net/b6sk7anr/, and `console.log('Prop changed');` is called

Comment: Thanks, but why should I avoid using {{ anyMethod(1) }}?

Comment: In your case, that's methods created infinite loop, in other cases - that has a poor performance, because methods don’t know if the values used in the function changed so they need to run everytime to check, but computed properties know if the values used in the function changed so they will be called only when values changes.